# Remove BrowserAction onClicked listner

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension in which I am adding `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback)` listners but I need to keep only one listner at a time and remove previous ones depending on some conditions but whats happening now is, It stacks all the previous listners and fires all of then when clicked. How can I remove previous listners and keep the latest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `removeListener` for all chrome events.

Something in the lines of

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(yourMethod);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener(yourMethod);
```

But why do you keep adding listeners? Wouldn't it be easier to customize the existing event handler depending on the current situation?

Comment: i need to change extension icon if page url matches some pattern and change accordingly if the page url changes or leads to some other url and alert user is he clicks when disabled icon is there. To achieve this i am using onUpdate and onActivated listners from chrome.tabs api